# Manipulation data on javascript

Tags: javascript

I have some codes like this

```
var f = document.frmR5B075;
var str = f.cbo_BilServProvCodeHidden.value;
var afterDash = str.substr(str.indexOf("-") + 1);
```

And i want put `afterDash` value back to `f.cbo_BilServProvCodeHidden.value`. I tried use `f.cbo_BilServProvCodeHidden.value = afterDash;` seems not working / cannot get the value. Any Solution ? Thanks

Comment: Can you create [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net) demo

Comment: can you share the html

Answer (score 0):

`f.cbo_BilServProvCodeHidden.value = afterDash` seems to work for me.

[Here is the demo](https://jsfiddle.net/y6377m2y/1/)